Raster Clipping not following the output extent
I'm having trouble with clipping raster in ArcGIS. I have a raster file that I want to clip in my study area (shapefile). I use the Clip Raster tool under the Data Management Tools, however the result shows a raster that does not follow the boundary extent of the output as shown in image 2. After this I tried using the Clip tool under the Raster Functions, which works perfectly as shown in image 3. However, when I reclassify the raster file in image 3, it resulted again in a raster that does not follow the boundary as shown in image 4.





It appears to be working as designed.  It looks like your raster has very large cells (pixels) - ie, very low resolution.  A cell has to be either included or excluded from the result.  You cannot clip part of a cell.  Only whole cells.
